# Out of Memory Exception when exporting data

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

I have an application which uses a Web Service to get data from SQL Server and exports it to an SQLite Database in my tablet. The thing is, the table has approximately 25,000 records. The code is working just fine when I limit it to, say, 100 records. But I am getting the following error when exporting ALL of the data:

```
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.initializeTable(ThreadLocal.java:244)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.rehash(ThreadLocal.java:325)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.cleanUp(ThreadLocal.java:254)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:438)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:359)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:992)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:799)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion(SQLiteDatabase.java:862)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:242)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at com.example.shvalidation.DatabaseHandler.InsertBook(DatabaseHandler.java:75)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen$TestThread.doInBackground(MainMenuScreen.java:79)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen$TestThread.doInBackground(MainMenuScreen.java:1)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-13 13:36:31.734: E/AndroidRuntime(12821):    ... 4 more
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821): Activity com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412636d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-772,216} that was originally added here
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412636d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-772,216} that was originally added here
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen$TestThread.onPreExecute(MainMenuScreen.java:49)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at com.example.shvalidation.MainMenuScreen.onCreate(MainMenuScreen.java:30)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-13 13:36:32.804: E/WindowManager(12821):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am wondering if anyone knows anyway I can export these records. Yes, I am aware that exporting over 25,000 records to SQLite is ridiculous, but unfortunately this is the project I've been assigned. And as such, I have to find a way to do it.

EDIT: Adding the code that uses the Web Service and saves to the SQLite.

```
package com.example.shvalidation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Activity {
    //JSON Variables
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String pid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);
        new TestThread().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void PlantToDome(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectLocationScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //Código del Web Service
    public class TestThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainMenuScreen.this, "Loading", "Loading data, please wait..");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void...args0) {
            int success;
            Book book = new Book();
            DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(MainMenuScreen.this);
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        "http://192.168.1.102:8080/WSBook.php", "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray("record"); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
//                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject record = productObj.getJSONObject(i);
                        book.setAoiName(record.getString("aoi_name"));
                        book.setExptName(record.getString("expt_name"));
                        book.setEuID(record.getInt("eu_id"));
                        book.setX(record.getInt("x"));
                        book.setY(record.getInt("y"));
                        book.setZ(record.getInt("z"));
                        book.setRaplo(record.getString("raplo"));
//                      Book book = new Book(record.getString("aoi_name"), record.getString("expt_name"), record.getInt("eu_id"), 
//                              record.getInt("x"), record.getInt("y"), record.getInt("z"), record.getString("raplo"));
                        handler.InsertBook(book);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #2: My JSON Parser class.

```
package com.example.shvalidation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("Unsupported Encoding", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Client Protocol", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Log.e("JSON Parser", json);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: SQLite can handle millions of records just fine. Apparently, your code (which you have not shown) creates too many objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you are trying to pull all 25,000 rows' data into memory first, then write them to SQLite (that is a guess, since you did not show any code, but I bet it's a good guess).  You will have to limit it to, say, 100 rows at a time.  That is, read 100 rows from the web service, then write them to SQLite, then read 100 more rows, etc.  You could get fancier with threads, but that should get you on the right path.

**Edit:** Thanks for adding your code.  It looks like the culprit is this line:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
    "http://192.168.1.102:8080/WSBook.php", "GET", params);
```

That tries to read the text of the entire table in from the web service and jam it into a JSONObject, which your phone does not have enough memory to handle.

I see two solutions:

1. If you can add parameters to your http get request that define row ranges, you could loop getting rows 0-99, write them to db, 100-199, etc., using almost the some code you have now.
2. If you cannot define row ranges, or the database changes frequently so that you cannot rely on that giving you consistent data, you will have to break up reading the response from the http request into chunks.  Unfortunately I am not well versed in all the json libraries out there, so I cannot say which may help with that process.

Comment: I dont know SQLLite database or Android Development , but looking at the solution - Solution suggested by you is best in this case.                                                     At first read of SQLite , you might also consider disk space increase or increase in Java Memory ( Might be bad idea on andriod device since space is a limitation)

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed the problem. I am now trying to find a way to limit the amount of records it reads and inserts. I'm currently reading per line so I don't know how to do that yet. I will keep trying and if I find a solution I will post it here. Thank you very much.